# Meteor webapp on different devices

Tags: meteor, chat

How do I run my meteor code on two different devices in the same network (using IP address).
I have a chatApp which I would like to test on two diff devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your host computer where you are running the meteor app check the IP address. In Windows use `ipconfig`, or in Linux-based OS use `ifconfig`

Meteor app usually runs in port 3000 unless you changed it.

In your "other" devices, enter the IP address including the port number of the host machine. Assuming your host's IP address is `192.168.0.101` and the port the app is running on is 3000, then it is `http://192.168.0.101:3000`